# How to use define_method in a mixin?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Hi I'm trying use a mixin to define some method using define_method. I would like to do something like

```
module A
  %w(a b c d).each do |w|
     define_method(w) { "method #{w}" }
  end
end
```

So I can then do

```
class B
  include A
end

B.new.c # => 'method c'
```

But that doesn't work.

I've tried (almost) everything involving included, instance_eval class_eval etc... nothign work.

Is it possible to do  ?

## Update

There were initially a syntax error in the example I posted, but that wasn't the real problem. I just made the example for the post, that wasn't the real example (which a bit too long to be posted).

My problem was I used a comma in my list `%w(a, b, c, b)` instead of `%w(a b c b)`

Therefore, `a,` was defined instead of `a`. Silly me, (hard to spot though).

Seeing that it works for you guys helped me solving the problem, thanks

Comment: well, it works for me (R 1.8.7)

Comment: You're missing an `end` in your module. How is it not working? Is there an error message?

Comment: @matt that wasn't the problem see update. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't the module be:

```
module A
  %w(a b c d).each do |w|
     define_method(w) { "method #{w}" }
  end
end
```

that is, the `end` was missing.